# Grouping Fields/Properties under a class

Tags: c#, winforms

The title may be a bit confusing but I'm trying to do something like,

```
public class Configurations
{
    public int TableRow;
    public int TableColumn;
    public string TableName;

    public void SaveSettings(){ }
    public Configurations LoadSettings(){ }
}
```

And when you create an instance for the `Configurations` class (from within another class), like,

```
Configurations settings = new Configurations();
```

You can access all the properties inside the class, but I want to, instead, group them inside another class, say `Property`,

```
settings.TableRow              // I do NOT want this visible/accessible here
settings.Property.TableRow     // this is what I want instead
settings.SaveSetting();        // only the methods should be accessible on the parent
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this via inheritance or attributes assigning on the class. Can anyone please give me some pointers on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just create another class that contains this settings?

```
public class Configurations
{
    public TableProperties Property = new TableProperties();

    public void SaveSettings(){ }
    public Configurations LoadSettings(){ }
}

public class TableProperties
{
    public int TableRow;
    public int TableColumn;
    public string TableName;
}
```

Comment: You have to create the class (preferably in a new code file) and use that class as variable / property.